# How to make a bulleted list (menu) with dotted lines

Tags: css, positioning, less

I'm trying to make a bullet list / menu with dotted lines in-between each anchor tag.

On the rollover, the background turns pink and there should be an adequate amount of spacing between it and the dotted line:

[image: Comp showing horizontal items separated by pink dashed lines.]

This looks okay, but when I switch to a mobile layout, the positioning of the dotted lines are totally off.

Here is my CSS:

```
li {
    background: url('images/dotted-line.png') repeat-x 0px 41px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    color: @darkpink;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 8px 8px 8px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 195px; /* 188 */
    cursor: pointer;
    .textshadow(); /* less minim */
}

a:hover, a.selected {
    border-radius: @radius;
    background-color: @darkpink;
    .textshadowdark();
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I am just wondering if it's a good/bad idea to put the background dotted line on the `li` tag. Is it better to just reposition the image in a media query, or to put the image on the `anchor` tag instead?

Comment: See if you can grab a screenshot of your mobile layout. On a mobile device or emulator.

Comment: then don't use a picture for that. just the a border-bottom:1px dotted pink; for li. I don't know the color code for your pink out of my head.

Comment: It's all right the pink is a variable so I have it at the top of my page anyhow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah I agree with Sven, use something like this:

```
li {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ce1443;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I went with `dashed` because `dotted` can be a bit much, and your screenshot above looks more like a `dashed`.  I just grabbed a quick screengrab for the color.

Also... Are you trying to make this mobile only? Or is it supposed to be responsive? Might want to switch over to some `em` sizes so it'd be more relative to the screen size.

Comment: I agree dashed looks better than dotted :)

Comment: Much better and easier to manage...the dotted line I'm using is actually a bit more complicated but I think I am going to go with this with a text-shadow...otherwise I will be positioning this all over the place.